# Using SQLite in Codename One Application

Tags: java, sqlite, codenameone

I have a working sqlite db which I have place in my /src folder.
I then went onto the Codename One website and followed their doc example

```
    Database db = null;
    Cursor cur = null;
    try {
        db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("MyDb.db");
        if(query.getText().startsWith("select")) {
            cur = db.executeQuery(query.getText());
            int columns = cur.getColumnCount();
            frmMain.removeAll();
            if(columns > 0) {
                boolean next = cur.next();
                if(next) {
                    ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
                    String[] columnNames = new String[columns];
                    for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                        columnNames[iter] = cur.getColumnName(iter);
                    }
                    while(next) {
                        Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
                        String[] currentRowArray = new String[columns];
                        for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                            currentRowArray[iter] = currentRow.getString(iter);
                        }
                        data.add(currentRowArray);
                        next = cur.next();
                    }
                    Object[][] arr = new Object[data.size()][];
                    data.toArray(arr);
                    frmMain.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Table(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, arr)));
                } else {
                    frmMain.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query returned no results");
                }
            } else {
                frmMain.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query returned no results");
            }
        } else {
            db.execute(query.getText());
            frmMain.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query completed successfully");
        }
        frmMain.revalidate();
    } catch(IOException err) {

        frmMain.removeAll();
        frmMain.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Error: " + err);
        frmMain.revalidate();
    } finally {
        Util.cleanup(db);
        Util.cleanup(cur);
    }
```

However when I run the example and try and execute a simple select query I get this error ...

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: MyTable)
```

- So I have added the DB
- I have used the 'openOrCreate' statement

Have I missed a step?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the input guys.

Unfortunately none of the advice worked for me. 
However I did solve it in the end.

It turns out that there is a folder in my home directory called '.cn1/database'. Once I placed the DB into this folder it worked.

Two things:
1] If the db does not exist then it will create it and place it into this directory
2] The db does not show up anywhere in Netbeans (well not that I could see anyway)

Thanks again

Comment: imho manually copying the file solves the symptom, not the problem...  the file must get copied for the build to work, otherwise everyone running this will have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure that you current working directory at execution is `./src` ?

Try

```
db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("./src/MyDb.db");
```

or open with absolute filename:

```
db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("/path/to/src/MyDb.db");
```

Comment: Isn't the code moved out of src when it is compiled?

Comment: @cricket_007 `openOrCreate("MyDb.db");` tries to open in the current working directory. That can be anywhere and depends how `java`is launched. If from IDE, it is probably the parent directory of `src`, but this is only a guess. Absolute filename will work always.

Comment: Right. I just know Eclipse and Intellij create a build/target folder and the class files aren't where the src folder is, so assets should not be assumed to be there, relative to the code. I haven't used CodenameOne

Answer (score 0):

You can try this cn1lib https://github.com/shannah/cn1-data-access-lib

I have used it and it works a charm, except doesn't work for 2 tables in the same query and can't perform delete operations.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html):

> Some SQLite apps ship with a "ready made" database. We allow you to
>   replace the DB file by using the code:
>
> `String path = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath(“databaseName”);`
>
> You can then use the FileSystemStorage class to write the content of
>   your DB file into the path. Notice that it must be a valid SQLite
>   file!
>
> **Important:** getDatabasePath() is not supported in the Javascript port. It
>   will always return null.
>
> This is very useful for applications that need to synchronize with a
>   central server or applications that ship with a large database as part
>   of their core product.

You are relying on paths that make sense in the simulator, in the device you need to copy a resource into location. Check out the SQL demo where this is implemented: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/sql-demo-revisited.html

Comment: I needed to first create the `databases` directory myself in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to copy database to Codenameone storage after put the database file in src folder, the database will copy to directory ".cn1/database" after running

```
String DB_NAME = "DBNAME.db";
Database temp_db = Database.openOrCreate(DB_NAME); //To create an empty file before copy, otherwise Android will throw file not found exception
temp_db.close();
String p = Database.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
OutputStream o = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(p);
InputStream i = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/" + DB_NAME);
Util.copy(i, o);
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a complete answer.

I'm going through the demo, and something seems to be missing:
Shouldn't a build task copy this db resource to the correct target folder? Otherwise how can a deployment ever work? (if the db doesnt get packaged up then how will it get deployed?)  without it the app cant run